# Will using extern C keyword for a specific header in C++ allow for conversion from void* to char*?

Tags: c++, c

I am using an open source hydrodynamics code written in C. They have a lot of functions for reading and writing Input/Output parallely. I am writing a program to do post analysis of outputs in C++, and I want to use these functions in my code by including their header file. Problems such as `printf` etc are taken care of when I include the header file (a.h) within

```
extern "C" {
#include "a.h"
}.
```

But when I try to compile it an error shows up saying

/Src/Parallel/al_io.c:234:5: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
   a = (void *)va;

Which means it is not allowing this in spite of the `extern` keyword. Is this normal? If so is there another way to allow these functions to work. Editing each of them by hand is not possible as there are about thousands of them.
Thanks!!

Comment: No, `extern "C"` doesn't change the language from C++ to C, it merely assigns linkage to names...

Comment: Is “al_io.c” the file you wrote containing `extern "C"`?  If not, why are you compiling it as C++?

Comment: @DavisHerring "al_io.c" is a file from a third party library that I'm using. Its completely written in C, but the file I am writing is a C++ one where I want to use the functions in al_io.c .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this normal?

Yes. `extern "C"` changes the linkage. The program is still compiled as a C++ program.

In the implementation of a `extern "C"` function, you have access to all the features of C++. The flip side of it is that it is compiled just like a regular C++ function. All the syntactic constraints of a C++ program apply to such a function.

> If so is there another way to allow these functions to work.

You can use `static_cast<char*>(...)`.

Comment: an "C" declared C++ function cannot be forced with different parameters list

Comment: @JacekCz true, but what does it have to do with that answer (or the question, for that matter)?

Comment: re: "all C++ features apply" All minus one

Comment: @JacekCz, That is a constraint in general, not specific to *In the implementation of an `extern "C"` function*

Comment: @JacekCz that's about the definition, not the declaration. The declaration must essentially be a C function declaration, overloading not included indeed.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> /Src/Parallel/al_io.c:234:5: error: invalid conversion from 
>     ‘void*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive] a = (void *)va;
> ```

You need to compile this third-party C library as C, not as C++.

As you have discovered, wrapping the third-party library's headers in `extern "C"` does not do that.  (You do still need to do this, or the program as a whole will fail to link, but it doesn't fix your immediate problem.)

What *does* do that is using the correct "compiler driver" to compile each source file.  You didn't tell us which compiler you're using, or anything at all about how you are building the program, so I can't be terribly specific about that, but: make sure you are using a program named something like "cc", "gcc", or "clang" to compile all files named `whatever.c`, *not* a program named something like "c++", "g++", "clang++".  Compilers with "++" in their name should only be used to compile source files that actually contain C++ code.

When it comes time to link all the `.o` files together into a complete program, you will either need to use the compiler with "++" in its name to do that, or you will need to name the C++ runtime library explicitly on the command line (e.g. `gcc foo.o bar.o baz.o -lstdc++`).  The name of the C++ runtime library can vary and can be difficult to discover, so I recommend the former approach.

Comment: I actually wrote a makefile to compile all the files that need to be linked to compile this. And I'm using mpi++(which is a C++) compiler to compile all the files together. Is it possible to compile the C files seperately using gcc from the makefile? Or does all files that I compile with the makefile have to be the same type?

Comment: @ShyamHarimohanMenon If you have a compiler called "mpi++", then you should also have a compiler called "mpicc".  Use that for the C files.  If you don't have that, you need to install it, it's probably a sibling package from the same supply where you got "mpi++".